# VS Code Python intelli-sense not working in my code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am new to use vs-code , but it not work very fine on my code.
Show as bellow, both `line` and `line2` can't show all `QLineSeries` method.?
[image]

The Extensions:
[image]

Comment: Have you installed the Python extensions from marketplace?

Comment: Yes, I had install it.